# Webview Images OnClick Listener

Tags: image, webview, onclick, listener

I Have A Layout That Contain WebView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffe86000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custombordergray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am loading html file from asset folder in it.

img src='file:///android_asset/images/bhuikot.jpg' width="100%" height="auto"

xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz

In Html File I Have Some Images and Text.

```
    public class Antur extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // FULLSCREEN
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.killa_name);

        TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //in your OnCreate() method
        myAwesomeTextView.setText("AAAAA");

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // Loading an html page into webview
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webview/antur.html");
    }
}
```

When I Click On That Image I Want To Open that Image In Another Activity.

Thanks In Advance